# Malfunctioning audio from a Tascam DR-60DMKII

Tags: audio-recording

I use a [TASCAM DR-60DMKII](https://www.tascam.eu/en/dr-60dmkii) for audio recording in a Stage show performance. I record audio by TRS cable in 2R channel only, one channel.

It is fine when it records, however not everyone can hear the audio when I mix it with video using [Filmora](https://filmora.wondershare.net/filmora-video-editor.html?gclid=Cj0KCQiAnNacBhDvARIsABnDa69JaAoM-JsO5PQx-44jwqlLkum3oWYgqXzD_Xi61CcTTfpkjMaqef8aAv79EALw_wcB). But some *can* hear the audio. WAV is the recorded audio format.

Does anyone know anything about this type of issue? (I'm not professional by any means, so please help me to get this solved.)

Comment: Hi Ebin. There's not a lot of info in this question, so as it is, it's pretty impossible to answer and likely to be closed. We need as much as you can explain, like what device you actually recorded in 2R, what plays it ok and what doesn't. What you did in Filmora. But *by far* the best thing you can do is share a link to the file in question (or a sample of it). That would help us to help you with your recording issue.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it is recorded with one channel only. Sound quality is ok. i am editing video in Filmora so i added the audio to synchronize. My video is in youtube but you can hear only with earphone.

Comment: Q1: Did you pan it into the middle, or do you want it to be R or L? // Q2: Is the recorded audio below about 400 Hz? Depending on the device (monitor, mobile) speakers stop producing loud enough signals below that, while headphones still do work.